# how to change default index page to login page in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to set my default index page to login instead of the dashboard in react js please help I am new to **react js**.

```
 const routes = [
  { path: '/', exact: true, name: 'Home' },
  { path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard }
]
```

this I how I am routing the pages in react router.

Comment: can you update question with your router ?

Comment: We need to know, what you have tried to give you solution. Are you using CRA, react router and which version of react router you are using etc.

Comment: Off Topic: @Nilesh, You have the `package.json` in the parent of build folder.

Comment: yes it is their

Answer (score 4):

try this

```js
// Router.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Login from '../screens/Login';
import Dashboard from '../screens/dashboard'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom"

class App extends Component {



  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
          <Route path="/dashboard/:id" component={Dashboard} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and in your main app.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Routers from './Router/Router';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
     <Routers />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

don't forget to install `react-router-dom`